How is Satan going to and from earth in Job if he was cursed and could only crawl in Genesis?
In Genesis 3:14 we read, "You will move on your belly
and eat dust all the days of your life." Then in Job 1:7 we read, The Lord asked Satan, “Where have you come from?” “From roaming through the earth,” Satan answered Him, “and walking around on it.” How is Satan walking when in the beginning he was curse could only move on his belly. Is this the same being?

There is no data supporting the co-identification of the Edenic serpent with the character "Satan". This tradition post dates the completion of the Hebrew bible, see God's Monsters by Esther HaMori for discussions of the serpent of Gen

Avi, I agree with your insight. I don't understand why scholars have linked the two together. Thank you!

'Move (according to) the belly' (the seat of carnal appetites) and 'eat dust' (the earthly sustenance of the carnal) does not imply 'crawling on the ground'. That is so only by allusion. That the Entity is restricted to what is natural, created and carnal does not deny that Entity access to the second heavens (the place of created spirits).

Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17.000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. Moderators are elected by the Community of users to maintain the intergrity of the site.. Welcome to SE-BH.

Taking two different verses so widely apart in context is not usually a good foundation for a question, though I see what you're asking is more of a theological based concern due to human teaching rather than Biblical. Is this understanding that the serpent in the Garden of Eden is as  explained there actually Satan? 2 Corinthians 11:3 comes close ("But I fear, lest somehow, as the serpent deceived Eve by his craftiness, so your minds may be corrupted from the simplicity that is in Christ."), but Paul didn't make this supposed connection as far as I can see.

@Avi actually there is sufficient evidence there is and it’s spelled out for you too “And he seized the dragon, that ancient serpent, who is the devil and Satan, and bound him for a thousand years,”
‭‭Revelation‬ ‭20‬:‭2‬ ‭but that’s not the point of the question which is misreading the fact that he is going to and fro ON the earth and there is an assumption clearly based on modern cosmology where the OP thinks the sons of God in the council were meeting.

There is a lot here. Serpent (Seraph) 'singular' may be the beginning of enemy 'plural'. An interesting question would be more like, why does the "serpent of old" in the beginning evolve into a 7 headed dragon in the end? The singularity of the serpent gains not only contemporaries, but global influence as well. I like Nigel's explanation that the belly is empty and will 'crawl' roam the earth, and will spend his days seeking to devour dust (flesh). The idea of a snake is metaphorical and not literal. Why does a snake morph into a dragon with wings if cursed to crawl literally?

"Don't miss the forest for the trees" At some point we have to understand we don't have all the answers. The previous text clearly states, 'Now the serpent was the most cunning of all the wild animals that the Lord God had made. He said to the woman, “Did God really say, ‘You can’t eat from any tree in the garden’?”' (Gen. 3:1 HCSB) This serpent was created by God himself and this wild animal could talk. The text goes on to read, "Then the Lord God said to the serpent: 'Because you have done this, you are cursed more than any livestock and more than any wild animal.You will move on your belly and eat dust all the days of your life. I will put hostility between you and the woman, and between your seed and her seed. He will strike your head, and you will strike his heel.'" (Gen. 3:14-15) This passage of scripture is always referenced by Christian as prophecy of Jesus and his enemy satan. My point of asking this question was to help open ones eyes to see that these are two separate entities. We are dealing with a natural entity that has the ability to talk and reproduce. I can accept what @ray grant says, "The Serpent was a real animal, to be sure. But it was "possessed by Satan", and used to tempt Eve."

+1 Great answer using the context of the scripture!

Scriptures for ConsiderationThe use of a Serpent to represent Satan is profuse in Holy Scripture, and was not the result of later extra-biblical theology:

And the Lord God said to the woman, "What is this that thou hast done?" And the woman said, "The Serpent beguiled me, and I did eat." (Genesis 3:13)...And the LORD God said, I will put enmity between thee (the serpent) and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel." (3:14-15) Note: most Christian scholars consider this the "proto-evangel" describing the conflict between Jesus and Satan during the Passion week!


And the Seventy returned with joy, saying, "Lord, even the devils are subject unto us through your Name.And He said to them, "I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven. Behold I give you power to tread on serpents and scorpions, and over all the power of the enemy...Notwithstanding  in this rejoice not that the spirits are subject to you, but rather rejoice because your names are written in heaven." (Luke 10:17-20) The link between the imagery of reptiles (serpent) and satanic powers is glaringly apparent! Compare Mark 16:17-18.


And the great dragon was cast out,  that old Serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceives the whole world. He was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him. (Revelation 12:9) *Compare the word "deceive" with the connection mentioned by Paul in his letter to the Corinthians: "But I fear lest by any means, as the Serpent beguiled (deceived) Eve through subtilty, so your minds should be corrupted from the simplicity that is in Christ." (2 Cor. 11:3)

How is it Possible?So what does the imagery of Genesis mean, when we read of Satan galivanting around the earth causing havoc, instead of "crawling"?
The answer lies in the "ability of Satan to possess individuals---and animals." All throughout Jesus's earthly ministry---and later, the Apostles' ministry---we read of Jesus casting out demons from people. The Seventy, whom Jesus commissioned, also exorcised demons. In one instance, Jesus exorcised demons (a legion of them) from a mad man, and sent them to possess a herd of pigs (swine.)
It is hermeneutically safe to conclude that in the Genesis story, Satan possessed the serpent. And the rest of Scripture backs this up by associating the deceptive powers of Satan as that of the Serpent! (Revelation 12:9 especially!)
However, Satan often, also, appears as a Tempter, Adversary, Accuser of the brethren, in the Bible, as a "person" or "personality", without any connection to an animal. (Ephesians 6:11-16, 1 Petr 5:8, Zechariah 3:1-2, Job 2) So whether as an animal or as an appearance as a man, it is the same Satan. So there is no confusion nor mystery here.



so what you are saying is that this animal that God make is only an image. Genesis 3: 1 "Now the serpent was the most cunning of all the wild animals that the Lord God had made." In my view this context should be viewed as literal, I don't see where the author was using imagery and for what purpose?

@RomanDeLeon - The Serpent was a real animal, to be sure. But it was "possessed by Satan", and used to tempt Eve. Possession is a real ploy. Recall how Satan "entered Judas" in the N.T. to perform an evil deed.

I can except that the serpent was possessed by satan. Thank you!

Being cursed to eat dust is a metaphor of being brought low. In the Book of Job, the term is ha-satan (the adversary) not the proper name Satan, and in Genesis the serpent is a serpent, not further identified. Later theologians would make the connection that results in the OP's question.
Indeed outside of the Book of Job the character called "satan" is found only once in the entire Hebrew Bible:
1 Chronicles 21:1

A satan rose up against Israel, and he incited David to take a census
of Israel.

Ha-satan in the Book of Job is a member of the divine council who reports directly to God. His identity as the serpent arises from later biblical theology, based primarily on the Book of Revelation. But even here, Satan does not crawl in the dust. He is cast down from Heaven:
Revelation 12:7-9

7 Then war broke out in heaven... The huge dragon, the ancient
serpent, who is called the Devil and Satan, who deceived the whole
world, was thrown down to earth, and its angels were thrown down with
it.

Conclusion: Satan is not directly described as a serpent in the OT. In the Book of Job he is one of the "sons of God" who confers with the Lord in the divine council. In the Book of Revelation he does not crawl in the dust but is cast down from from Heaven in the Last Days. The idea that Satan, as a serpent, literally crawls on the ground and eats dust is metaphorical.

Genesis 3: 1 clearly states that the serpent was created by God. "Now the serpent was the most cunning of all the wild animals that the Lord God had made." He was a created wild animal. He did not take on the form of an animal this is not a spiritual accusation here.

@RomanDeLeon I do not understand the meaning of "this is not a spiritual accusation". Not sure it is accurate to say "he was created as a wild animal." He is highly intelligent, able to communicate with humans, and to engage in theological discussion.

Dan Fefferman, I did not say this, the scripture speaks for it's self. Genesis 3: 1 "Now the serpent was the most cunning of all the wild animals that the Lord God had made." My reason for asking this creation is to get an better understand of why the tradition of scholars use this verse as an account of this being satan.
